# static std::condition_variable undefined reference

Tags: c++, c++11, static, condition-variable, undefined-reference

```
class Test  
{
 public:
    Test();
    static std::condition_variable condVar;
    void notifyCv(); // тут делаем condVar.notify_all()
}
```

при попытке использовать такую переменную - выдает undefined reference.

```
void main()
{
    std::mutex mut;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);

    while (true) {
        Test::condVar.wait(lock);
        //далаем чтото полезное
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что создается много экземпляров класса Test, и в этих экземплярах происходит событие, которого нужно постоянно ожидать. А реагировать нужно, если произошло событие в ЛЮБОМ экземпляре.

Если объявлять condVar, не как static, то у каждого экземпляра будет по своему condVar и как тогда ожидать событие от любого из экземпляров, не перебирая их все постоянно в цикле?

upd:
да, вопрос похож на дубликат..
то, что static переменную нужно определить - я знаю. Но не пойму, как это сделать с condition_variable..

Comment: Что касается непосредственной ошибки - это прямой дубликат. Что касается самой идеи использования статической переменной - это вопрос отдельный...

Comment: @AnT Предложенный вами вопрос не про 'cond_var'.. С 'int' все понятно. Наверное сразу надо было написать, что у меня проблема не с самим static как таковым, а с непониманием способа определения статических условных переменных. Так вообще можно?

Comment: А прямо над main написать что то вида  `std::condition_variable Test::condVar;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась с помощью комментария @KoVadim.

вне объявления класса добавить:

```
std::condition_variable Test::condVar;
```